# Passing intents to next activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, position

I am trying to save listview selected position in a string and passing to next activity as shown below:

I have set my listview default selection to first row by setting it as :

```
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
lv1.setItemChecked(0, true);
lv1.setSelection(0);
```

Declaration variables:

```
int myposition;
String myvalue;
```

LIstView ItemClick:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
          myposition=position;
          myvalue = String.valueOf(myposition);
        }
});
```

This is how I move it to next activity using button click:

```
btnNxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Step3Activity.class);
            // Pass a single position
            i.putExtra("selposition", myvalue);
            // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
            startActivity(i);
           }
});
```

This is how I get the intent on the newActivity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
// Get a single position
position = i.getExtras().getInt("selposition");
myvalue = String.valueOf(position);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            myvalue,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But it always gives me the position '0'. So am i getting this by setting the default selection of 1st row ? Can anyone clarify me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this to get the value:

```
position = Integer.parseInt(i.getExtras().getString("selposition"));
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: @AndroidKiller-Thanks...That helped me out

Comment: @coder if it worked and helped you, then you may think to accept it. :)